# A weird TEEE noise is coming in mic and I don't know how to fix it

Tags: microphone

Somehow there is a strong static noise in my mic and it sounds like TEEEEEEEE. It's not regular a buzzing sound. I have checked the mic's jack by using it in my phone and it was working really fine, no buzzing, no static nothing. So i thought maybe there is issue with my external sound driver ( i use external sound driver because motherboard mic jack sucks) so i purchased a new one and I also purchased a usb hub because motherboard's usb are very loose and it fixed it JUST FOR SOMETIME. Months later, that TEEEEEEE static sound came back, i again checked the jack of the mic and there was no problem.

So i had to use mic so I found a app which allows you to use your phone mic wirelessly and yes you can connect your external mic to your phone and connect it with the pc version of the app using wifi. I was surprised when I use it, quality of the mic become kinda low but not that much, there was 0.1s delay which was not noticeable,but I wanted to use it at highest quality. That app also have usb connection option and so i tried it and i heard that TEEEE static sound again, even tho the mic was connected to my phone. I can only hear that sound if I use mic with usb feature, so is there a problem with my pc cables or something like that? Is there a problem with the power supply? My guess is that there is a cable which is broken and current is coming out of it but i don't think that the problem, if this was the problem then i would get electric shock every time I touch any parts of the pc. There is some power related issue i guess.

About power supply, i am using it for like 3-4 years
Can you guys please help me to fix issue? If this static noise keeps coming, i won't be able to use any expensive microphone on it later, for now that app is the alternative. The app name is WO mic

Comment: This sounds like a grounding issue (or yes, noisy power supply)

Comment: Does a different mic have the same issues?

Comment: Yes,  that sound can be heard even on a camera mic if its connected to pc, i have also tested that mic for recording on my camera and it seems to work just fine. That noise only come when it is connected to by pc by camera or by anything else